# using lodash .groupBy. how to add your own keys for grouped output?

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js, grouping, lodash

I have this sample data returned from an API.

I'm using Lodash's `_.groupBy` to convert the data into an object I can use better.
The raw data returned is this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "jim",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "33"
    },
    {
        "name": "eddie",
        "color": "green",
        "age": "77"
    }
]
```

I want the `_.groupBy` function to return an object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        color: "blue",
        users: [
            {
                "name": "jim",
                "color": "blue",
                "age": "22"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sam",
                "color": "blue",
                "age": "33"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        users: [
            {
                "name": "eddie",
                "color": "green",
                "age": "77"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Currently I'm using

```
_.groupBy(a, function(b) { return b.color})
```

which is returning this.

```
{blue: [{..}], green: [{...}]}
```

the groupings are correct, but I'd really like to add the keys I want (`color`, `users`). is this possible using `_.groupBy`? or some other `LoDash` utility?

Comment: As of 2024, there is no need to use lodash, underscore.js or alikey anymore, since [native `groupBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77997731/17487348) is now available.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You can do it like this in both Underscore and Lodash (3.x and 4.x).

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "jim",
  "color": "blue",
  "age": "22"
}, {
  "name": "Sam",
  "color": "blue",
  "age": "33"
}, {
  "name": "eddie",
  "color": "green",
  "age": "77"
}];

console.log(
  _.chain(data)
    // Group the elements of Array based on `color` property
    .groupBy("color")
    // `key` is group's name (color), `value` is the array of objects
    .map((value, key) => ({ color: key, users: value }))
    .value()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy("color")
    .pairs()
    .map(function(currentItem) {
        return _.object(_.zip(["color", "users"], currentItem));
    })
    .value();
console.log(result);
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/WYCF8/)

**Note:** Lodash 4.0 onwards, the `.pairs` function has been renamed to [`_.toPairs()`](https://lodash.com/docs#toPairs)

Comment: Very nifty, but hard to wrap my head around. Can you explain the steps in between, especially the pairing and zipping (and the double zip, since `_.object` is an alias for `_.zipObject`).

Comment: Print the result after each step. It might help you understand better. If you have specific question please let me know. I'll help you with that

Comment: lodash 3.10.0 and some logging for every step: http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/WYCF8/171/. It's still a puzzle, but I'm getting there. Haven't used `_.zip` and `_.pair` so much yet.

Comment: In lodash 4.x, the `pairs()` method does not exist anymore. An updated lodash 4.0 version of this example is: `.chain(data).groupBy('color')                 .toPairs().map(function (pair) { return _.zipObject(['Name', 'Suppliers'], air); }).value();`

Comment: I feel like loadash should have a function that does this very exact thing.  I would think users would want to group an array of objects by a property all the time.

Comment: I am getting Object instead of values [ { color: '0', users: [ [Object], [Object] ] } May be a newbie issue - help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The updated version to this answer which worked well is:    
`var result = lodash.chain(res)
    .groupBy('color')
    .toPairs()
    .map(function(currentItem) { return lodash.zipObject(['color', 'users'], currentItem) })
    .value();`

Comment: Using `_.chain` is considered a bad practice now.

Comment: @ErikSchierboom what is air? You mean `pair` !

Answer (score 124):

Isn't it this simple?

```
var result = _(data)
            .groupBy(x => x.color)
            .map((value, key) => ({color: key, users: value}))
            .value();
```

Comment: This seems much cleaner to me, and appears to be returning the same results.  Thanks!

Comment: wow. what syntax is this? First time seeing that you can pass the array into the constructor

Answer (score 31):

Highest voted answer uses **Lodash `_.chain` function which is considered a bad practice now** ["Why using `_.chain` is a mistake."](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba)

Here is a fewliner that approaches the problem from *functional programming* perspective:

```
import tap from "lodash/fp/tap";
import flow from "lodash/fp/flow";
import groupBy from "lodash/fp/groupBy";

const map = require('lodash/fp/map').convert({ 'cap': false });

const result = flow(
      groupBy('color'),
      map((users, color) => ({color, users})),
      tap(console.log)
    )(input)
```

Where `input` is an array that you want to convert.

Comment: I tried to use `flow()` instead of `chain()` here, but typescript's type checking simply go crazy with composed functions. I hope we have the same level of support we currently have in RxJS's `pipe()`, for example, in lodash.

Comment: I really like your map() syntax, very cool `map((users, color) => ({color, users}))` instead of `map((value, key) => ({ color: key, users: value }))`

Comment: The problem of preventing treeshaking only applies to Lodash. In Underscore, you can customize which functions get mixed into `_` since version 1.11.

Answer (score 26):

another way

```
_.chain(data)
    .groupBy('color')
    .map((users, color) => ({ users, color }))
    .value();
```

Comment: Similar to @thefourtheye's answer but a bit easier to understand

Answer (score 8):

Thanks **@thefourtheye**, your code greatly helped. 
I created a generic function from your solution using the version 4.5.0 of Lodash.

```
function groupBy(dataToGroupOn, fieldNameToGroupOn, fieldNameForGroupName, fieldNameForChildren) {
            var result = _.chain(dataToGroupOn)
             .groupBy(fieldNameToGroupOn)
             .toPairs()
             .map(function (currentItem) {
                 return _.zipObject([fieldNameForGroupName, fieldNameForChildren], currentItem);
             })
             .value();
            return result;
        }
```

To use it:

```
var result = groupBy(data, 'color', 'colorId', 'users');
```

Here is the updated fiddler;

https://jsfiddle.net/sc2L9dby/

Answer (score 6):

Other answers look good by using `lodash`.

And I would suggest a different approach by using JavaScript, such as `Array#reduce`, `object for storing` and `??=` syntax. As a result, it just takes `O(n)` time complexity.

- Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to aggregate data.
- Using [`logical nullish assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) only assigns if `acc[color]` is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) (`null or undefined`).

```js
const data = [{ "name": "jim", "color": "blue", "age": "22" }, { "name": "Sam", "color": "blue", "age": "33" }, { "name": "eddie", "color": "green", "age": "77" }];

const result = data.reduce((acc, {
  name,
  color,
  age
}) => {
  acc[color] ??= {
    color: color,
    users: []
  };
  acc[color].users.push({
    name,
    color,
    age
  });

  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an updated version using lodash 4 and ES6

```
const result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy("color")
    .toPairs()
    .map(pair => _.zipObject(['color', 'users'], pair))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Example groupBy and sum of a column using Lodash 4.17.4**

```
   var data = [{
                "name": "jim",
                "color": "blue",
                "amount": 22
                }, {
                "name": "Sam",
                "color": "blue",
                "amount": 33
                }, {
               "name": "eddie",
               "color": "green",
               "amount": 77
              }];

      var result = _(data)
                   .groupBy(x => x.color)
                   .map((value, key) => 
                   ({color: key,
                    totalamount: _.sumBy(value,'amount'),
                    users: value})).value();

                    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different approach, using [my own library](https://github.com/elclanrs/essential.js) you could do this in a few lines:

```
var groupMe = sequence(
  groupBy(pluck('color')),
  forOwn(function(acc, k, v) {
    acc.push({colors: k, users: v});
    return acc;
  },[])
);

var result = groupMe(collection);
```

This would a be a bit difficult with lodash or Underscore because the arguments are in the opposite order order, so you'd have to use `_.partial` a lot.

Answer (score 2):

### ES2024

You can now use the built-in [`Object.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) or [`Map.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy) in conjunction with the good old [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). No need for `lodash`, `underscore.js` or alike anymore:

```js
const input = [
  {
    name: "jim",
    color: "blue",
    age: "22",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    color: "blue",
    age: "33",
  },
  {
    name: "eddie",
    color: "green",
    age: "77",
  },
];

const usersByColor = Object.groupBy(input, (user) => user.color);
const result = Object.entries(usersByColor).map(([color, users]) => ({
  color,
  users,
}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

> [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_groupby) is ok (~ 82% as of 2024-02-15) but not great yet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const groupBy = (array, key, name) => {
    return array.reduce((result, obj) => {
      result[obj[key]] = result[obj[key]] || {
        location: obj[name],
        child: [],
      };
      // result[obj[key]] ??= {
      //   location: obj[name],
      //   child: []
      // };
      result[obj[key]].child.push(obj);
      return result;
    }, {});
  };

  const items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      age: 75,
      name: 'Kumar',
      location: 'chennai',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      age: 25,
      name: 'Christo',
      location: 'Dindigul',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      age: 28,
      name: 'SK',
      location: 'chennai',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      age: 21,
      name: 'Ram',
      location: 'chennai',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      age: 21,
      name: 'ravi',
      location: 'chennai',
    },
  ];

  let obj = groupBy(items, 'age', 'location');
  const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [obj[key]][0]);
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

**In 2017 do so**

```
_.chain(data)
  .groupBy("color")
  .toPairs()
  .map(item => _.zipObject(["color", "users"], item))
  .value();
```