# How can I group data with an Angular filter group by?

Tags: group-by

I have a list of players which belong to a group each. How can I use a filter to list the users per group?

```
 [   {
     "UserID": 61267,
     "FullName": "Steve",
     "Permissions": [
       {
         "PermssionType": 1,
         "PermssionStr": "team alpha"
       }
     ]   },   {
     "UserID": 61268,
     "FullName": "George",
     "Permissions": [
       {
         "PermssionType": 1,
         "PermssionStr": "team alpha"
       },
       {
         "PermssionType": 2,
         "PermssionStr": "team beta"
       }
     ]   },   {
     "UserID": 50825,
     "FullName": " Gene",
     "Permissions": [
       {
         "PermssionType": 1,
         "PermssionStr": "team alpha"
       },
       {
         "PermssionType": 2,
         "PermssionStr": "team beta"
       }
     ]   } ]
```

I'm looking for this result:

- team alpha

  - Gene
  - George
  - Steve
- team beta

  - Gene
  - George

Comment: You can use lodash, here is another topic for grouping elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600897/using-lodash-groupby-how-to-add-your-own-keys-for-grouped-output You can also check this, its really useful: https://dustinpfister.github.io/2018/08/02/lodash_groupby/

Comment: perhaps you haven't understood my mind well