# REACT - I want to filter array to take item has the same date and make new array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to group items based on date.

To show note items in html same date have same have same group.

Filter method works but how to take also date.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
const [noteData,setNoteData]=React.useState([{
    id: Math.random(),
    headline:"sample 1",
    innerText:"lorem ipsum sit dolar ametlorem ipsum sit dolar ametghbjknlmşöds asopıhgpduhfgopa doırg oıdsğoınrgh ğıhsğoın ğoısğ orıo sğı oo ",
    date:"25.02.2022"
  },{
    id:Math.random(),
    headline:"sample 2",
    innerText:"",
    date:"24.02.2022"
  },{
    id:Math.random(),
    headline:"sample 6",
    innerText:"lorem ipsum sit dolar amet",
    date:"23.02.2022"
  },])
  const [secondNoteData,setSecondNoteData]=React.useState([])

  //* local storage get notes
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const localNotes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-note-app-data'));
    if(localNotes){

      setNoteData(localNotes)
    }
    console.log(localNotes)
  },[])

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setSecondNoteData(noteData)
  },[noteData])

  //* local storage set notes
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if (noteData) { // added if check, to check wether noteData variable has value if yes then set the value in localStorage else not.
      localStorage.setItem('react-note-app-data',JSON.stringify(noteData))
  }  },[noteData])
   
  //* item return new array depends date 

  //* notes

  const notess= secondNoteData.filter((item)=>{
    return item.date== "25.02.2022"
    //* this return based on spesicfic date
    //* ı wanna grupize depends on date.
    })

    console.log(notess)
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: If you are able to use Lodash, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600897/using-lodash-groupby-how-to-add-your-own-keys-for-grouped-output

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create nested objects:

```
const notess = secondNoteData.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const date = item.date;
    acc[date] = acc[date] ? acc[date].push(item) : [item];
    return acc;
}, {})
```

this will return an object where each key is a date, and the value will be an array of all notes of the same date, for example:

```
{
    "25.02.2022": [{...item}, {...item}]
    "anotherDate": [{...item}]
}
```

Comment: acc not defined, but actuallly  ı don t get it, ı know reduce but is  there any simple value. ı just wanna order notes with their date and make it outomatic

Comment: Oh, you said "I want to group items based on date", I thought that was what you meant. You can use `sort` and use a custom function to order by the date